# After viewing a question, hit the back button, new SO questions are on the main page instead of the state I left the page in

Tags: discussion

Question about the functionality of the SO main page.  If I open a fresh browser, view a question, read it for a few minutes and then hit the `Back` button, the main list of questions has changed (i.e. new questions are on top, along with recently answered questions, etc...)

Is this functioning as designed?  I ask because I'll often see 2 questions that interest me, I click the first one, read/answer/vote on it, and then try to go back and find the second question but it's usually gone/"not-where-I-left-it" and I don't want to spend time trying to find it.

SO gets so many questions that if I spend a minute or more reading one post, by the time I go back a lot of activity has occurred on the main page.

I did see some previous posts asking about [votes not being visible when clicking the back button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68008/going-back-after-voting-shows-the-page-without-my-vote-in-chrome) ([this post is similar as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77846/why-is-page-state-not-preserved-when-using-browser-back-and-forward-buttons)) but from those posts it sounds like my page should in the state it was before I click the link, not refreshed updated.

Normal?

Comment: I think this is by design, but just a tip to avoid the problem: use tabbed browsing! My workflow is to go through the whole list, open a few that interest me each in a new tab, and then just do them one at a time at my leisure.