# Don’t lock on second vote if it’s the same as first one

Tags: feature-request, voting, locked-votes

The following happened to me at least a half-dozen times:

1. Open a question page
2. Vote on a question or answer, then go and do something else
3. Navigate to the *pre-vote* version of the same page (either through having it opened several times during a Google search, [pressing the back button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77846/318145) or something else)
4. Vote *the same way* once again.
5. “*You last voted on this* [*question or answer*] *an hour ago. Your vote is now [locked in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80762/318145) unless this* [*question or answer*] *is edited*.” **UPD**: I misunderstood this message, see below. The question is moot.

While this isn’t terribly important, I understand this is a security mechanism triggering for no substantial reason. It would be good if this didn’t happen. (It would make sense for voting to be idempotent in this situation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My misunderstanding, sorry: I believed that the lock is triggered on the *second* vote while in fact the message only indicates that the *first* vote is locked.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't really care whether your vote marker shows a vote already or not. So, if you go to any post you've voted on and cast the same vote again, you get the same message... the reason for this is that when you're still in the window or if the post has been edited clicking the vote button a second time after the vote is already cast will *remove* the vote (if you're within the window).

So, when you click the vote button, it's still correct... you can't change your vote... meaning you can't remove it.

If you don't like the warning, you can refresh the page before you try to vote if the page has been sitting around for a while. This will update the vote count and show whether you've already voted or not. But, as you say, it's a minor thing.