# When going back in the browser to where you've added a comment - the comment is missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, browsers, back-button

If I'm on an SE question page, and:

1. Add a comment to the question or to an answer
2. Visit another URL on the same browser tab
3. Press back

the comment I added is missing.

This is not a new issue, I've had it since forever - with Firefox on Linux.

Comment: More things are missing, like votes you've cast. This could be a general browser trait rather than an SE bug ...

Comment: That's a reasonable explanation, repro the same on Chrome, Firefox, Brave /Windows for probably 7 years.

Comment: An explanation for what's going on - [Why is page state not preserved when using browser Back and Forward buttons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77846/why-is-page-state-not-preserved-when-using-browser-back-and-forward-buttons)

Comment: @Catija: But can't SE pages could have a script which detects this situation, and updates the page with newer content?