# Upvote/Downvote disappears when you edit a question and then back out

Tags: bug, edits, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Going back after voting shows the page without my vote in Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68008/going-back-after-voting-shows-the-page-without-my-vote-in-chrome)

When I upvote/downvote, then click edit on the question to either see what the edit was or to edit it myself, only to back out by clicking the back button, my upvote/downvote disappears.  If you refresh/reload the page, the upvote/downvote is back, as it should be.

** *Note that I've only tested this in Chrome 10* **

Answer (score 4):

If it was caused by pressing the browsers back button and a refresh fixes it, I don't call that a bug.  If you look hard enough, you can see this behavior in many places.

Comment: why not? the bug is that prior to clicking edit the vote was there and by going back to the page via the back button, it was not.

Comment: @Scott: clicking the back button is akin to reloading the page how you originally saw it.  Since you hadn't voted yet when you originally saw it, the browser correctly didn't show the vote.

Comment: Ok, well screw me.  Just figured it's something that could confuse people and that could possibly be handled to force a refresh when the back button was clicked.

Comment: @Scott: Just saying I don't think this is a big deal at all.