# I am not able to figure out whether I voted or not and this is wasting my effort

Tags: bug, design, voting, accessibility

I am not able to figure out whether I voted or not because of the colour of up and down buttons and this is wasting my effort because I do try to vote and then it tells me that I have already voted. No, I am not colour blind.

[image]

Zoom of arrows

[image: Zoom of arrows]

Update:
How exactly am I now able to see the selected button in different color! Has something been fixed here?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the button does not change color when you click on it?  When I look at posts, if I voted, the buttons are different colors.  If I did not vote, they are the same color.

Comment: Did you try refreshing the page?

Comment: I do see a **minor** difference between the two voting buttons in your image, you're probably using some extension for the dark mode you see there, disable it and use the dark theme built into Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can you add which stackoverflow theme you use? Light/Dark/System? Is the high contrast option enabled or not?

Comment: There is actually a bug, it's been here for months (years?). It happens to me especially when I keep a tab open for a long time (maybe when I close my browser and reopen it?). So many times I get this message when I vote that I had already voted for this question/answer. It is NOT a contrast issue. Just a refresh issue.

Comment: I just tried restarting my browser (Firefox) and indeed my upvote on this question isn't shown until I refresh the page.

Comment: @Vince please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68008/going-back-after-voting-shows-the-page-without-my-vote-in-chrome).

Comment: Your issue is not the same as the one described in this post @Vince

Comment: @sam yeah, if OP using the Light theme of SO and the Dark theme we see in the screenshot is result of userscript or browser extension, this can also explain the problems.

Comment: The newest screenshot confirms that this is a Dark Reader phenomenon, not something the site dark more is doing. I'm not sure asking for better support of the Dark Reader extension on Stack Overflow makes sense when there's already been work put in to the first-party dark mode.

Comment: Moving to leave this closed since extension and user script issues are considered out of scope for this site. Before posting a report here, it is expected that users disable extensions and user scripts.